# Are there any good ways to speed up IE when running watir-webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, watir, watir-webdriver

I am running a suite of roughly 200 test cases that take about 45 minutes running Chrome. When I use IE, the tests take almost 2 hours and suffer from intermittent errors that are coming from timeouts.

I have read that turning the screenshots off will help, but that does not seem to have been much help.

Comment: Turning off screenshots could help if you take a lot of screenshots. Why are you taking a lot of screenshots?

Comment: In support of Željko's comment, here is an article about that issue from Alister Scott: http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/13/are-your-ie-webdriver-tests-running-slow-maybe-its-the-screenshots/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only significant time improvement in running tests that I know about is to run them in parallel. The other option is to get involved in development of [Internet Explorer driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) and make it faster. :)

Comment: Yes, running in parallel is a big improvement

Answer (score 2):

One of the other ways to make tests run even faster on IE would be to use [watir-classic](http://github.com/watir/watir-classic). This works only if you're not using too much watir-webdriver specific stuff - e.g. not accessing underlying selenium-webdriver driver instance directly in your tests and so on. If you're using the public API then it should work quite well.

I'm not aware of how to make tests to run in parallel on Windows, because the popular library [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) does not work on this platform.